# User login using Parse iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, parse-platform

I have a block of code the simply authenticated the user's credentials. Part of the app also is the process of creating an account and I am utilizing Parse API's in all scenarios where data is stored remotely/validated.

I have the following process created already in code:

1. User sees landing page and selects to login or signup
2. User decides to signup and data is stored remotely using Parse
3. User then attempts to login and input is validated against whats stored in Parse table.
4. User proceeds to main view of the app.

I want the user once logged in (after signup) to bypass the process of logging in every time. I thought of using SSKeyChain.

Here is my code for login:

```
NSString *email = _emailTxtView.text;
        NSString *password = _passwordTxtView.text;



[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:email password:password
        block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
            if (user) {

                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainSegue" sender:self];
            } else {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Error" message:@"Credentials provided were incorrect. Please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

            }
        }];
```

How can I achieve that? is SSKeyChain the right API to use? or is there a much forward way of doing it?

Comment: Do you really mean "after reinstall"?

You can't persist data across a reinstallation of the app. Each app generally has its own keychain which is cleared when an app is uninstalled. -- Though it is possible to share a keychain with other apps from the same developer, I don't think that will help your situation.

Comment: Sorry corrected that...was typing and didn't think about it thoroughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parse SDK keeps the user logged in for you. You shouldn't try and persist the user's password and run the login method each time. Try only showing your login view if `[PFUser currentUser] == nil`

Comment: Ah so guarding the code above I would use if([PFUser currentUser] == nil)?

Comment: That should do it. If it doesn't, there's likely something else wrong, but I'd be happy to help you figure that out.

Comment: @Fabian is saying that you don't even need to show a login view if there's currentUser.  If  there's a current user, you can instead say @"Hi %@!", currentUser.username, and offer a logout button.

Comment: Right. Don't just guard the above code. Guard the entire presentation of your login screen.

Comment: of course that would be done but I was just making sure that I understood the guarding part. What is shown as a consequence of an authorized user, will certainly impact the flow. Nonetheless, thanks guys really apprecaite it. @Fabian I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Fabian I placed the code in the viewDidLoad body in the main view controller. It seems like it skips the login always even when user was deleted from Parse table. Should it be placed somewhere else?

Comment: Deleting a suer from the table isn't really what you want to check against. It should be fairly rare. You should see what happens on a fresh install, or after you log out.